# Minimum sampling rate to detect rising edges in PWM

Tags: sampling

I have a 20Hz PWM signal (0 - 5V) with a duty cycle of 30%. What would be the minimum/recommended sample rate to count all rising edges in this signal? I'm unsure because Nyquist does not really work with all the harmonics in the spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

The pulse duration is 0.05 s, so the pulse is high for 0.015 s. Ideally, a sampling interval of 0.015 s would guarantee at least one sample when the pulse is high; however, to be safe you want to avoid sampling near the edges, and allow for some pulse duration jitter. I'd suggest $1/0.01 = 100$ as the minimum sampling rate.

Note that Nyquist is not relevant to this problem: you only need to consider it when your objective is to reconstruct the original signal from its samples.

Answer (score 1):

If your signal is $F=20Hz$ PWM with 30% duty cycle, you would have $0.05s$ period $T$ and $0.015s$ pulse width $w$.

Such signal has a sinc-like spectrum with harmonics spacing $1/T=F=20Hz$ and zeroes spacing of $1/w \approx 66.7 Hz$

Windowing first three sinc side lobes (so 4 zeroes) should be enough, so you can choose pre-discretization filter with width $W \approx 266.7 Hz$ and choose

$Fs \geq 2*W \approx 534 Hz$

Answer (score 1):

Per definition, a $20$ Hz PWM signal has $20$ rising edges per second, for any duty cycle except $0$ and $100 \%$ (where there are no edges).

You would choose a sampling rate based on what resolution you need. For example if you sample at $200$ Hz you have a resolution of $\frac{20}{200} = 10 \%$. Sample at $2000$ Hz and you have a resolution of $\frac{20}{2000} =  1 \%$.